# ReactJS + D3: Parse local CSV file and passing it to state with d3-request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, jsx

This might be a really simple thing to do and there are multiple Q&A regarding this, but i can't find a solution to my problem..

I'm trying to parse an entire CSV file with d3-request module and set the state with this data in a React component. From my understanding the d3-request module parses each row of the CSV file one by one, so I can't simply do this:

```
import {csv} from 'd3-request';

  componentWillMount() {
    csv('./data/test.csv', (error, data) => {
      if (error) {
        this.setState({loadError: true});
      }
      this.setState({
        data: data
      });
    })
  }
```

So i thought of doing this instead. The "..." or spread syntax helps to copy each array.

```
  componentWillMount() {
    csv('./data/elements-by-episode.csv', (error, data) => {
      if (error) {
        this.setState({loadError: true});
      }
      this.setState({
        data: data.map(d => ({...d}))
      });
    })
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.data);
  }
```

But the console.log prints out the html contents of the page itself.

**test.csv**

```
  'title', 'A', 'B'
  'E01', 1, 0
  'E02', 5, 0
  'E03', 10, 2
```

Hoping to transform CSV to this, after parsing:

```
this.state.date = [
  ['title', 'A', 'B'],
  ['E01', 1, 0],
  ['E02', 5, 0],
  ['E03', 10, 2]
];
```

**EDIT:**

Seems that the problem in the first place is reading in the CSV file using d3-request in React app.

```
  componentWillMount() {
    csv('test.csv', (error, data) => 
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

Console log prints out the HTML structure of the page....

Answer (score 20):

I was facing the same error some time ago and a way to solve it is as follows.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import data from './data.csv';

d3.csv(data, function(data) { console.log(data); });
```

You need to import your dataset first using React's method "Import" and then parse it using D3.csv function.

Hope it works for you! All the best.

Edit: I am using D3.js 5.5.0 and React.js 16.4.1 and using Yarn to start the application.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. Tell me, how did you figure out this one?

Comment: @KibongeMurphy Sorry for my late respones. I figured it our because I was working with D3,js and ReactJS to create statistical graphs components for the frontend team and in D3.js you have a lot of tools to work with. Serendipity I would say. Cheers!

Comment: Be aware in this way you includes data in your final react build, this would increase your final react production size.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. I'm using the `create-react-app` to create a project (React v 16.13)

Comment: Thanks! This was so simple. Why people need additional packages for this stuff :)

Comment: The console logs `Promise {<pending>}`  how do you get the data to log?

Answer (score 6):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import './App.css';

import * as d3 from 'd3';

import data from './data_set/data.csv';

class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
}

componentDidMount() {

    d3.csv(data).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    }).catch(function(err) {
        throw err;
    })
}

render() {


    return ( 
             <div className = "App" >
              <div> Data Visualization </div> 
             </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Making use of promises will do the job ;).

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Create React App, there are some special instructions for using files inside the public directory.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

As Feras mentioned in their comment, importing will bundle the data along with your application code, which might not be what you want.

From within React code, you need to prepend `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` to the file path in the public directory.  So in your case,

```
componentWillMount() {
    csv(process.env.PUBLIC_URL+'/test.csv', (error, data) => 
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```