# Can't read CSV file in my project's folder structure using d3

Tags: reactjs, typescript, d3.js

I am a bit new to React.
The problem: I have a folder structure -

- my_folder_name
- - Utils.ts
- - test_csv_file.csv

I tried reading this CSV file in my `utils.ts` like this:
`

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';

const getCSVData = () => {
 d3.csv('./test_csv_file.csv', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

It throws the error:
`GET http://localhost:3000/test_csv_file.csv net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

I checked several examples but can't find it and have spent almost a day fixing this:
[ReactJS + D3: Parse local CSV file and passing it to state with d3-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51258615/reactjs-d3-parse-local-csv-file-and-passing-it-to-state-with-d3-request)

Edit1:
example of my csv:

```
01104,Offizier - Geoinformationsdienst
01104,Offizier - Militärfachlicher Dienst
01104,Offizier - Militärmusikdienst
01104,Offizier - Sanitätsdienst
01104,Offizier - Truppendienst
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've placed your csv correctly in your project?

Trying it this way, it works fine for me.

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import csv from "./test_csv_file.csv"

const getCSVData = () => {
    d3.csv(csv).then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: My csv is in the same folder as my utils file. This is a react project using TypeScript, would that make any difference?

Also, this is an example of my csv file:

01104,Offizier - Geoinformationsdienst
01104,Offizier - Militärfachlicher Dienst
01104,Offizier - Militärmusikdienst
01104,Offizier - Sanitätsdienst
01104,Offizier - Truppendienst